# Difference between $arr[$key] and $value in PHP

Tags: php, arrays, foreach, key

Let's say I got following code:

```
$arr = array("1" => 1, "2" => 2, "3" => 3, "4" => "4", "5" => "5");
foreach($arr as $key => $value) {
    echo "Array[".$key."]: " . $arr[$key] . "<br>";
    echo "Value: " . $value . "<br>";
    if (isset($arr[$key+1])) $arr[$key+1] = $arr[$key+1]*2;
}
```

which creates this output:

```
Array[1]: 1
Value: 1
Array[2]: 4
Value: 2
Array[3]: 6
Value: 3
Array[4]: 8
Value: 4
Array[5]: 10
Value: 5
```

Now my question is, why does $value differ from $arr[$key] while iterating through said array? Is $value not getting updated with the array because foreach is just handling a copy of the array or something? Can I solve this issue without using $arr[$key] inside of the loop?

Comment: See: http://stackoverflow.com/q/10057671/3933332

Comment: Yes, as you are using the same array, it is making a copy while iterating till you write to it.

Answer (score 0):

As far as i know PHP uses "copy on write", so everything is a reference until you try to write to it, at that time a copy is made where you will write to.

So yes, that means your value for the array you are iterating over is different than the set-by-index value.

Also see:

[How does PHP 'foreach' actually work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10057671/how-does-foreach-actually-work)

Answer (score 0):

I have the answer for what happens but not why it happens.

```
value are *2 when index are in series

if array is (1=>1,2=>2)
than o/p is in $arr[$key](for each) 1 value 1,2 value 4

if array is (3=>1,2=>2)
than o/p is in $arr[$key](for each) 3 value 1,2 value 2

if array is (2=>1,3=>2)
than o/p is in $arr[$key](for each) 2 value 1,3 value 4


if array is (1=>5,3=>2,4=>'3',6=>8)
than o/p is in $arr[$key](for each) 1 value 5,3 value 2,4 value 6,6 value 8
```

Answer (score 0):

`foreach($arr as $key => $value) {
    $value=$arr[$key];
    echo "Array[".$key."]: " . $arr[$key] . "<br>";
    echo "Value: " . $value . "<br>";
    if (isset($arr[$key+1]))
         $arr[$key+1] = $arr[$key+1]*2;
}`

i think you should assign manually `$value=$arr[$key];` in for loop ,for getting output you want.

In `foreach`, `PHP` iterates over a copy of the `array` instead of the actual `array`. In contrast, when using `each( )` and `for`, `PHP` iterates over the original array. So, if you modify the array inside the loop, you may (or may not) get the behavior you expect.